# iOS auto layout coordinates and programmatically drawing views

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have a view constrained with auto layout in the storyboard.  I want to draw a core graphics element and add it partially overlapping the view.  The issue is positioning.  The storyboard view won't get its final size until the viewdidlayoutsubviews is completed.

If I try and draw the overlapping element in the viewdidlayoutsubviews method the viewdidlayoutsubviews will be called again and will loop indefinitely.  If I add the overlapping element in the viewDidAppear method it does work correctly.  The issue with the viewDidAppear is that there is a half second delay in the element drawing to the screen.  I would like it to draw and appear with the rest of the screen at the same time.

I have a few thoughts on how to proceed

1. Draw the element on another thread while invisible and then move it to the desired location after layout is completed and make it visible.
2. Remove the elements from the storyboard and make all the elements programatically.
3. Create the element with autolayout in the viewDidLoad method and let the auto layout system position it. (Not really sure how I would do this one)

What would be the best recommended method for getting from where I am to the screen drawing all elements at the same time?

Comment: Have you tried doing it in viewWillAppear?  Another option, albeit less elegant, is to set a flag, and set it to false after the first time, so it only executes the drawing once.

Comment: "I want to draw a core graphics element": Core Graphics draws into a context. What is providing the context? Are you creating a `CGImage` or a `UIImage`? Are you drawing in a view in `drawRect:`? Something else?

Comment: The context is coming from a cgrect in my viewDidLoad.  I am drawing it with the drawRect  method.

Comment: viewWillAppear comes before viewdidlayoutsubviews giving me an incorrect element position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about calling the setNeedsDisplay() of your GC element (or whichever way you're drawing it) once from viewDidLayoutSubviews

You could just use GCD's dispatch_once like this:

```
var token : dispatch_once_t = 0
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    dispatch_once(&token, { () -> Void in
        cgthing.setNeedsDisplay()
    })        ...
}
```

Comment: This does work.  Not sure if its better than a boolean control flag.  Thanks for the help!